# Why this code is fast for char *?

Tags: c++, c++11

In [this talk by Sutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnqTKD8uD64) at 1:15:26 it was presented a code like below,

```
class employee{
 std::string name_;

public:
template<class String, class=
 std::enable_if_t< !std::is_same<std::decay_t<String>, std::string>::value > >
void set_name(String && name)
   noexcept(std::isnothrow_assignable<std::string &, String>::value)
  {
    name_ = std::forward<String>(name);
  }
}
```

I know how `std::forward` works, if `name` is a lvalue, `name_` will get copy constructed; and if `name` is a rvalue, `name_` will get move constructed. But in the slide it also says that `Optimized to steal from rvalues (and more)`, what is more?

And later it shows that this code seems the fastest among all the four implementations, especially for `char *`, anybody has the patience to walk through this code and explain what more is being optimized and why it is the fastest, particularly in the case of `char *` ?

Comment: Note the functions he is comparing against take a `std::string` in one form or another.  If your goal was just to write code that was fast for `char *` you don't _have_ to use perfect forwarding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, note that the code contains a typo and that the `enable_if` constraint does not do what's discussed even with the typo removed; In particular the function just won't work with `char*`, so obviously it's not the fastest with `char*`. You can see a question I asked about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26147491/365496) along with a 'corrected' perfect forwarding setter (along with the endorsement of this version from Howard Hinnant).

```
template <class String>
auto set_name(String&& name) 
-> decltype(name_ = std::forward<String>(name), void()) {
    name_ = std::forward<String>(name);
}
```

The benchmark that's used for the presentation is calling `set_name` repeatedly on an `employee` in order to show the case where the member `string` gets to reuse its capacity instead of there being a memory allocation every iteration. The difference between the tall bars and the short bars shown in the benchmarks is the difference between reusing capacity vs. doing an allocation every iteration.

The reason the corrected perfect forwarder is fast with `char*` is because the instantiation of the template for `char*` just forwards a `char*` instead of needing to construct a `string` param in order to call `set_name` with an actual `string` object parameter. The assignment inside the setter is fast because `string` implements `operator=(char*)` that does the efficient memcpy into its existing storage and extra allocations are avoided.

So the claim `Optimized to steal from rvalues (and more)` is because perfect forwarding does nothing but forwarding. Not only does it pass through an rvalue if it gets an rvalue, but it also doesn't convert types, meaning that optimizations the "forwardee" implements such as `string`'s `operator=(char*)` get exposed as well.

Comment: I see. Upvote for "Not only does it pass through an rvalue if it gets an rvalue, but it also doesn't unnecessary convert types".

Comment: your `set_name()` doesn't return anything, and it has a return type

Comment: @BЈовић: The return type (after SFINAE) is `decltype(void())` so `void`.

Comment: @bames53, one more question, what is the purpose of `name_ = std::forward<String>(name)` inside `decltype`,  and with the same one inside the function body, which `name_ = std::forward<String>(name)` will get executed first?

Comment: @bames53, I almost understand it now, `name_ = std::forward<String>(name)` inside `decltype` is to [use SFINAE to detect operator support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839357/detect-operator-support-with-decltype-sfinae),  but `name_ = std::forward<String>(name)` will get executed twice? one time inside `decltype`, and second time inside the function body?

Comment: @Allanqunzi No, the expression inside the `decltype` is not evaluated

Comment: @Praetorian, thanks, more detailed explanation on this is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231075/is-expression-inside-decltype-executed-or-just-being-checked-for-validation)